# ASP.NET Wizard - Need onload of WizardStep

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspwizard

When I got to WizardStep, I like to populate some info depending on what was selected in the previous WizardStep. Is there is onload of a wizardstep where I can populate info into it based on certain conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`ActiveStepChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.wizard.activestepchanged%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) event:

```
void OnActiveStepChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dennis. I do not see though how I can trap what WizardStep it will go to with the OnActiveStepChanged.

Comment: You can retrieve the active step object through the `Wizard.ActiveStep` property and its index through the `Wizard.ActiveStepIndex` property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.wizard.activestep%28v=vs.80%29.aspx